# Python Pygame ошибка в коде. argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Gun

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

> File controls.py, line 34, in update

> File MAIN.py, line 22, in run

> File MAIN.py, line 24, in

Main.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
from bullet import Bullet
import controls
from gun import Gun
from pygame.sprite import Group

phon = pygame.image.load('paint\game\GameScreen.png')

def run():
    pygame.init() #иницилизация pygame
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0),pygame.FULLSCREEN) #полный экран
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Adventure") #Название игры
    gun = Gun(screen)
    bullets = Group()

    while True:
        controls.events(screen, phon, gun, bullets)
        gun.update_gun()
        bullets.update()
        controls.update(screen, phon, gun, bullets)

run()
```

bullet.py:

```
import pygame

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screen, gun, phon):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 16, 48)
        self.color = 223, 55, 55
        self.speed = 1
        self.rect.x = gun.rect.x
        self.rect.top = gun.rect.top
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.speed
        self.rect.x = self.x  
    def draw_bullet(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

controls.py:

```
from operator import ne
import pygame
import sys
from bullet import Bullet

def events(screen, phon, gun, bullets):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:          #Кнопка нажата
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #вправо
                gun.mright = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: #влево
                gun.mleft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #вверх
                gun.mup = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #вниз
                gun.mdown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                new_bullet = Bullet(screen, phon, gun)
                bullets.add(new_bullet)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:            #Кнопка отжата
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #вправо
                gun.mright = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: #влево
                gun.mleft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #вверх
                gun.mup = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #вниз
                gun.mdown = False

def update(screen, gun, phon, bullets):
    screen.blit(phon, (0, 0)) #обновление фона
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    gun.output()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

gun.py:

```
import pygame

class Gun():

    def __init__(self, screen):

        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SH1.png') #Картинка корабля
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.screen_rect.x
        self.rect.y = self.screen_rect.y
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.mright = False #вправо
        self.mleft = False #влево
        self.mup = False #вверх
        self.mdown = False #вниз

    def output(self):
        
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    def update_gun(self):
        if self.mright and self.rect.right <= 950: #Если нажата кнопка вправо
            self.rect.x += 2
        if self.mleft and self.rect.left >= 0: #Если нажата кнопка влево
            self.rect.x -= 2
        if self.mup and self.rect.y >= 0: #Если нажата кнопка вверх
            self.rect.y -= 2
        if self.mdown and self.rect.y <= 952: #Если нажата кнопка вниз
            self.rect.y += 2
```

Comment: я удалил скриншот, потому что текст нужно прикладывать текстом (кнопка "Править" под вопросом), а в ваше микроспопическое изображение все равно никто не будет всматриваться.

Comment: Ну и из текста ошибки понятно, из-за чего она возникает, а следовательно понятно, как ее исправить.

Comment: @Эникейщик мне не понятно поэтому и спрашиваю. Почему всегда мне говорят что всё понятно но не говорят что именно нужно сделать если им понятно?

Comment: хорошо, переведу: первый аргумент в вызове функции должен быть типа pygame.Surface, а вы засунули туда тип Gun

Comment: @Эникейщик что нужно сделать? :(

Comment: у вас просят  pygame.Surface. Вы даете Gun. Что нужно сделать?

Comment: В какой строке ошибка то хоть?

Comment: @CrazyElf File controls.py, line 34, in update
File MAIN.py, line 22, in run
File MAIN.py, line 24, in <module>
P.S. Эникейщик удалил фото с ошибкой, а она сразу удаляется когда я закрываю программу. Пришлось писать вручную...

Comment: @CrazyElf я поправил чтобы было хоть понятно где ошибка

Comment: что там писать вручную??? Скопировал - вставил.

Comment: Дорогой @Эникейщик я писал, что ошибка удаляется когда я закрываю (крашится) программу. Приходится скринить успевать а потом что либо делать. Я работаю в Visual Studio Code там не показывает нормально ошибки после краша.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вызов функции в `main`:

```
controls.update(screen, phon, gun, bullets)
                        ^^^^  ^^^
```

Вот сама функция в `controls`:

```
def update(screen, gun, phon, bullets):
                   ^^^  ^^^^
```

Вы перепутали **порядок следования аргументов** при вызове функции `controls.update`.

В вот частности, чтобы не путать аргументы при вызове функций, и стараются инкапсулировать как можно больше сущностей внутрь классов, чтобы не гонять их из функции в функцию, а брать из полей класса нужные сущности по их реальным именам.

Comment: Лучший! Спасибо за правильное объяснение!